# How can I iterate through rows of a user defined table datatype and insert into a table?

Tags: sql-server

I created a user defined datatype in my database:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[QuestionList] AS TABLE (
    [QuestionUId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL);
```

I then pass this into my stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_ins
       @Title          NVARCHAR (100) ,
       @Questions      QuestionList READONLY,
       @TopicId        INT                           
AS 
BEGIN
```

Can someone tell me how I can take the contents of the Questions parameter, iterate through it and insert the contents along with an **incrementing QuestionNumber** into this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestQuestion] (
    [TestQuestionId] INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionNumber] INT              NOT NULL,
    [QuestionUId]    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Isn't your TestQuestionId already an incrementing number?

Comment: That's right but there are other reasons that I need QuestionNumber to increment. The table actually has more fields. I just didn't show those fields to simplify the question to its most basic.

Comment: Do you want `QuestionNumber` to be unique within `TestQuestion` or should it restart from `1` for each call to the stored procedure?

Comment: Restart from 1 for each call to the stored procedure. Actually I didn't show this but there is another parameter that makes it unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks that you don't need to iterate at all, simple set-based insert will do:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TestQuestion (
    QuestionNumber,
    QuestionUId)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
    QuestionUId
FROM @Questions
```